# htmlagilitypack extracting emails

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I am executing the following code to extract all the links of the page using htmlagilitypack. When I enter the URL https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ I don't get any error and the code works fine. The URLs are also extracted and displayed well. But if I enter any other URL like https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/12447 , then I get the following error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".  I am getting error in this line

```
OutputLabel.Text += counter + ". " + aTag.InnerHtml + " - " + 
                    aTag.Attributes["href"].Value + "\t" + "<br />";
```

Please help me out.  It may be minor mistake for you but Please dont mark it negative.

```
var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
var document = getHtmlWeb.Load(InputTextBox.Text);
var aTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
int counter = 1;

if (aTags != null)
{
    foreach (var aTag in aTags)
    {
        OutputLabel.Text += counter + ". " + aTag.InnerHtml + " - " + 
                            aTag.Attributes["href"].Value + "\t" + "<br />"; 
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the object reference error on this line: `var document = getHtmlWeb.Load(InputTextBox.Text);`

Comment: I am getting error in aTag.Attributes["href"].Value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like some of anchors does not have *href* attribute. E.g. in given page there is anchor:

```
<a name="post40566"></a>
```

So, `aTag.Attributes["href"]` returns `null` and you have an exception when you are trying to get this attribute value. You can change XPath to select only those anchors which have this attribute:

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
```

Or verify if attribute exists before accessing its value:

```
if (aTag.Attributes["href"] != null)
    // ...
```

Third option is usage of `GetAttributeValue` method and provide some default value which would be displayed for missing attributes:

```
aTag.GetAttributeValue("href", "N/A")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was searching from two hours on internet. It works fine. Can you please help me in an other problem. If I want to ignore the URLs of images, what will I have to add in the code

Comment: @user3783579 actually that's another question. If current problem solved, you should accept solution, and if you have another problem, create new question. Here is hint for your next problem - get `href` value and verify extension of link